# Magento - Display Attribute Admin Title

Tags: magento, attributes

How do I modify the following code block so that it will display ‘Plant Genus’ instead of the text ‘[hide]’

The relevant code is at:
\app\design\frontend\enterprise\style\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml

```
<?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is the attribute from the admin panel:
[image: admin view]

Comment: Why not call it 'Plant Genus' instead of '[hide]' in Garden Store? The Admin title is not supposed to be shown on the frontend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lucasnus - I dont think this is in the front end, but he has placed the attribute for us to see in a screen shot, the code he quoted is from the front end view.

However I think you are quite close to a solution, since this looks like a store attribute visibility issue.

In the admin panel if you change to the "Garden Store" scope, can you try to then change the attribute value to "Plant Genus" ?

If that does not work, maybe try the Main Website scope.

Do you have this problem with other products attributes?